# Architectural and design question about uploading photos from iPhone app and S3

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, ios4, amazon-s3

I want to allow users of an iPhone app to upload photos and use Amazon S3.  There are 2 ways I see going about this:

1. Upload from iPhone to my server, which proxies it then to Amazon S3.
2. Upload from iPhone direct to S3

For option 1, the security is straightforward. I don't ever have to tell the iPhone my S3 secret. Downside is that everything is proxied through our server for uploads which sort of defeats the purpose of going to S3.

For option 2, in theory it's better but the issue is how do you enable the iPhone (or any mobile app on a different platform) to write into my S3 bucket without giving it my secret?  Additionally, I'm not sure if this is a good design or not because the flow would be: iphone uploads to S3, gets the URL, then tells the server what the URL is so it can add it to our database to reference in the future. However, since the communication is separated into 2 legs (iphone->S3 vs iPhone->My-Server) it leaves it fragile as a non-atomic operation.

I've found some older info that references using [Browser-based Uploads using POST](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html) but unsure if that is still the recommended approach. I'm hoping for a better solution where we can just use the REST APIs rather than relying on POST.  I've also see the [AWS iOS Beta SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/), but their docs didn't help much and I found an [Amazon article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490) that was equally unhelpful as it cautions you on what **not** to do, but doesn't tell you an alternative approach:

> The mobile AWS SDKs sign the API
>   requests sent to Amazon Web Services
>   (AWS) in order to validate the
>   identity of the AWS account making the
>   request. Otherwise, a malicious
>   developer could easily make requests
>   to another developer's infrastructure.
>   The requests are signed using an AWS
>   Access Key ID and a Secret Access Key
>   that AWS provides. The Secret Access
>   Key is similar to a password, and it
>   is extremely important to keep secret.
>
> Tip: You can view all your AWS
>   security credentials, including Access
>   Key ID and Secret Access Key, on the
>   AWS web site at
>   http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials.
>
> Embedding credentials in source code
>   is problematic for software, including
>   mobile applications, because malicious
>   users can de-compile the software or
>   view the source code to retrieve the
>   Secret Access Key.

Does anyone have any advice on the best architectural design and flow for this?

**Update:** The more I dig into this, it seems that a bunch of pople recommend using the HTTP POST method with the json policy file as described here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html.

With this, the flow would be something like (1) iPhone makes request to my server, asking for policy file (2) server generates json policy file and gives back to client (3) iPhone does HTTP POST of photo + json policy to S3.  I hate that I'm using HTTP POST in an apparently kludgy way but it appears to be better because it removes the need for my server to store the photo at all.

Comment: Not adding an answer unfortunately: I see the same pros and cons of each route that you do. I can help with the S3 REST APIs, though; ASIHTTPRequest has slick S3 support: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the tip on ASIHTTPRequest.  Is there any reason it's preferred over the iOS Beta SDK that Amazon provides for AWS?

Comment: No reason that I know of. I'm just had good success with the ASI library in a wide variety of data transfer situations, so haven't bothered with anything else.

Comment: Joe, I don't think I can use iOS Keychain because it's meant to store sensitive data in a secure way so it can't be extracted by other users or malicious apps. However, the user themselves can extract items from it. See this: http://blog.crackpassword.com/2010/08/peeking-inside-keychain-secrets/

Comment: Update: Looks like there are ultimately 2 ways to do this. First, it can be proxied through my server which has downsides of placing my server in the middle of every transaction.  Advantage of this is there are fewer points of error with multiple legs of communication. Second approach is to use "pre-signed URLs" with AWS that Adrian Petrescu pointed out.

Comment: I've added an answer below that allows the iPhone to use the `PUT` method of the REST API, and delegates to the server the task of generating the part of the `Authorization` header that requires the secret. This way, you don't risk exposing the access key to anyone with a jailbroken iPhone, while you don't put the burden of uploading the file on the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've discussed this issue [on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56793&tstart=0) before. As I say there, the proper solution for accessing AWS from a mobile device is to use the [AWS Identity and Access Management](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) service to generate temporary, limited-privilege access keys for each user. The service is great, but it's still in beta for now and it's not part of the mobile SDK yet. I have a feeling once this thing is released for good, you'll see it out on the mobile SDK immediately afterwards.

Until then, [generate presigned URLs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/class_s3_get_pre_signed_u_r_l_request.html) for your users, or proxy through your own server like some others have suggested. The presigned URL will allow your users to temporarily GET or PUT to an S3 object in one of your buckets without actually having your credentials (they are hashed into the signature). You can read about the details [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth).

**EDIT**: I've implemented a proper solution for this problem, using the preview beta of IAM. It's [available](http://github.com/apetresc/awskeyserver) on GitHub, and you can [read about it here](http://apetresc.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/aws-key-server/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the AWS IAM. Too bad it's still in beta.  Can you elaborate on the "presigned URLs" solution you mention? Is this just using HTTP POST with json policy doc?

Comment: Hey TMC, I added more details (and two links) about presigned URLs to my answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: In my quick read, the client would have to request the pre-signed URL from my server since it's based on the AWS secret key.  Then it would use that pre-signed URL to do it's file upload.  So essentially, this is no different than the HTTP POST method mentioned earlier, correct?

Comment: You would still need a server of your own, but by using presigned URLs this server's job is much easier -- all he has to do is return a URL, not do the upload himself as hipplar is suggesting. That's a huge difference.

Comment: Presumably after the upload is completed to S3, the client should tell the server it was successful?  Additionally, why in the world does the AWS iOS SDK have "S3GetPreSignedURLRequest" which requires the access key to be on the client?

Comment: The access key is okay to be known by others. In fact, it's included in the URL of every request. It's the secret key that you have to be paranoid about.

Comment: Ah you're right. I was confusing "AWS access key" with "AWS *secret* access key".  Thanks for pointing that out. I'll now need to post a subsequent question on .NET code for signing the URL :)

Answer (score 5):

Upload to your server and then post to S3. From an architecture standpoint you will want to do this from your server. There are many things that could go wrong during the data transfer you can handle better on the server and if you want to store any data about the image you are sending to S3 you are probably going to have a server side call anyway.

Plus, your Secret Access Key is stored in a more secure environment.  Your own.

If you are worried about scalability and you are going to be doing a considerable number of S3 transfers I would consider hosting your server on and EC2 instance. Transferring data between the two is free (given you store you data in following data centers).

> There is no Data Transfer charge for data transferred between Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3 within the same Region or for data transferred between the Amazon EC2 Northern Virginia Region and the Amazon S3 US Standard Region." [Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

There are many post here on SO [Amazon - EC2 cost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158765/amazon-ec2-cost) (example) about the pros and cons of using EC2.

Comment: Major +1 for the EC2<->S3 info.

Comment: We run in Azure so moving to EC2 not an option.  I mentioned in my original post that my server being proxy doesn't appear to be the only way since amazon supports uploads by HTTP POST with json policy files. If there is a way to get away from my server being the middleman that is the ideal approach for obvious reasons.

Comment: I prefer to upload the image directly but still store a reference and meta data on my own web server db.

Comment: Uploading from the server does not scale well.

Answer (score 5):

You can upload directly from your iPhone to S3 using the REST API, and having the server be responsible for generating the part of the `Authorization` header value that requires the secret key. This way, you don't risk exposing the access key to anyone with a jailbroken iPhone, while you don't put the burden of uploading the file on the server. The exact details of the request to make can be found under ["Example Object PUT" of "Signing and Authenticating REST Requests"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html). I **strongly recommend** reading that document before proceeding any further.

The following code, written in Python, generates the part of the `Authorization` header value that is derived from your S3 secret access key. You should substitute your own secret access key and [bucket name in virtual host form](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) for `_S3_SECRET` and `_S3_BUCKET_NAME` below, respectively:

```
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import hmac
import sha

# Replace these values.
_S3_SECRET = "my-s3-secret"
_S3_BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket-name"

def get_upload_header_values(content_type, filename): 
  now = datetime.utcnow()
  date_string = now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")
  full_pathname = '/%s/%s' % (_S3_BUCKET_NAME, filename)
  string_to_sign = "PUT\n\n%s\n%s\n%s" % (
      content_type, date_string, full_pathname)
  h = hmac.new(_S3_SECRET, string_to_sign, sha)
  auth_string = base64.encodestring(h.digest()).strip()
  return (date_string, auth_string)
```

Calling this with the filename `foo.txt` and content-type `text/plain` yields:

```
>>> get_upload_header_values('text/plain', 'foo.txt')
('Wed, 06 Feb 2013 00:57:45 +0000', 'EUSj3g70aEsEqSyPT/GojZmY8eI=')
```

Note that if you run this code, the time returned will be different, and so the encoded HMAC digest will be different.

Now the iPhone client just has to issue a PUT request to S3 using the returned date and HMAC digest. Assuming that

- the server returns `date_string` and `auth_string` above in some JSON object named `serverJson`
- your S3 Access Key (not your secret, which is only on the server) is named `kS3AccessKey`
- your S3 bucket name (set to `my-bucket-name` above) is named `kS3BucketName`
- the file contents are marshalled in an `NSData` object named `data`
- the filename that was sent to the server is a string named `filename`
- the content-type that was sent to the server is a string named `contentType`

Then you can do the following to create the `NSURLRequest`:

```
NSString *serverDate = [serverJson objectForKey:@"date"]
NSString *serverHmacDigest = [serverJson objectForKey:@"hmacDigest"]

// Create the headers.
NSMutableDictionary *headers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[headers setObject:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *host = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.s3.amazonaws.com", kS3BucketName]
[headers setObject:host forKey:@"Host"];
[headers setObject:serverDate forKey:@"Date"];
NSString *authorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AWS %@:%@", kS3AccessKey, serverHmacDigest];
[headers setObject:authorization forKey:@"Authorization"];

// Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
NSString *postUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@.s3.amazonaws.com/%@", kS3BucketName, filename];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postUrl]];
```

Next you can issue the request. If you're using the excellent [AFNetworking library](http://afnetworking.com/), then you can wrap `request` in an `AFXMLRequestOperation` object using [`XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFXMLRequestOperation.html#//api/name/XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest%3asuccess%3afailure%3a), and then invoking its `start` method. Don't forget to release `headers` and `request` when done.

Note that the client got the value of the `Date` header from the server. This is because, as Amazon describes under ["Time Stamp Requirement"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html):

> "A valid time stamp (using either the HTTP Date header or an x-amz-date alternative) is mandatory for authenticated requests. Furthermore, the client time-stamp included with an authenticated request must be within 15 minutes of the Amazon S3 system time when the request is received. If not, the request will fail with the RequestTimeTooSkewed error status code. "

So instead of relying on the client having the correct time in order for the request to succeed, rely on the server, which should be using NTP (and a daemon like `ntpd`).

Comment: Shadowmatter is right. Uploading directly to S3 is the better option. His code worked great. I've [placed my fork into a gist](https://gist.github.com/coudron/5258947) that contains some example Python code in addition to the Objective-C code. This is also a great way to get around **Heroku's 30 second Request Timeout** issue.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the above but keep getting 405 error - method not allowed. Do I need to modify the bucket's policy to enable the above?

Comment: @maethorr Although I'm no longer on this project, I would expect a bad policy to generate a 401 or 403 error code. My best guess is that you're accidentally using _POST_ and not _PUT_?

Comment: @shadowmatter found out the issue. I PUT onto the wrong end-point (the website endpoint <bucketname>.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com instead of just <bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com). Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I m confused. Why would amazon come up w/ the ios sdk to upload data to s3 then tell us not to use it (*Embedding credentials in source code is problematic for software, including mobile applications, because malicious users can de-compile the software or view the source code to retrieve the Secret Access Key*)???

Comment: Joe, amazon provides an iPhone SDK which explains Dat's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

they might have provided the sdk for the purpose that maybe the application could permit authentication to individual s3 accounts? e.g an app that lets users store files in their own (user's) bucket instead of provider? i feel a security flaw in merging the keys with application and distributing it. anyone can (mis)use them once the keys are revealed anyhow (its never secure when you're giving it out). on the other hand, keeping the functionality reserved to server will keep your keys transparent to user,isn't it?