# Is it possible to secure access to images stored on AWS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have an iPhone app that needs to store images on AWS. I want to secure this so that if someone somehow gets access to the URL of the stored image they can't just hit the AWS server and see the image.

If that means I setup a backend (Ruby) API call where my iPhone app asks the backend for the image and then backend then fetches the AWS image data (bitmap data or something) and then passes it to the iPhone I am ok with that.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been asked before, check [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811017/how-to-store-data-in-s3-and-allow-user-access-in-a-secure-way-with-rails-api-i#10902025)

You will need a backend API of your own that provides temporary signed URLs for your S3 files, as the post suggests you can use the [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem for that which makes it really simple to generate this, but AWS provides a few SDK's for different languages which you can check on [the aws website under SDK & Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/).